# Save time to a file from url ping

Tags: bash

I have this part of code in bash. I have a file with urls and I take the first 4 pings from each url. I try to save the times of these url pings, but at final I only have in my file "times.txt" the last time of the last url. How can I do this?

```
 #!/bin/bash 

 while read url;
 do

    ping -c 4 $url | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 > times.txt 

 done < $1
```

Comment: it's obvious that `tail -1` will get only the last line, that's why you got *the last time of the last url.*

Comment: You have to use `>>` (append) in `>> times.txt` . `>` will override `times.txt` each time when it is called.

Comment: URL ? you mean FQDN

Comment: Yes, it 's with append! thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following code does:

1. Remove 'times.txt' files every time is called. You may change this by removing or commenting line 4.
2. Expect one URL per line, as it would be given to the **ping** command.
3. It will extract the average ping time, of 4 pings, in each URLs, and write this time to the **times.txt** file.

Since the script is reading from standard input, after you paste URLs in standard input you need to type CTRL+D to finish it, or it will expect more URLs.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ensures the script always starts with an empty file
rm -vf times.txt

echo 'After all URLs have been sent to this script,'\
   'press CTRL+D to finish it.'
echo 'It will exit *after* the last URL has been processed,'\
   'which may take some time.'

# Read URLs from standard input, one URL per line
while read url
do
    ping -c 4 $url | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' \
    | cut -d '/' -f 2 >> 'times.txt'
done
```